# VB.net Video file only playing music in windows media player

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vid.mp4") Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = True
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vid.mp4"

        Else
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("mywebsite.tk/vid.mp4", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vid.mp4")
            Dim sizeInBytes As String = FileLen(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vid.mp4")
checksize:
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            If sizeInBytes.StartsWith("1455") Then
                MsgBox("Succesfully downloaded. Click ok to install.")
                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = True
                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vid.mp4"
            Else
                GoTo checksize
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The video is not playing, it just plays some visualizers and the music.

[image: It shows this:]

Comment: After downloading the video, have you verified it is actually getting saved correctly?  I Would also suggest maybe look at modernizing your flow control.  GoTo is really a 20year hold over from old vb and shouldn't really be used now days

Comment: @Hursey yes, checked and the video did download correctly, and can play it with an external player. Don't use GoTo, but can you recommend something instead then? Also it works fine, just the video doesn't play like it should

Answer (score 0):

have had the same problem and there were codecs missing.